# Fonts on tablet looks a bit blurry

Tags: screen, fonts

This is hard to explain in a technical manner as I do not know the proper terms, but it has something to do with cleartype / font anti alising.

The font in my phone looks so much better than on my tablet. I tried to screenshot it (on my tablet) but it looks fine when the screenshot is sent to a different device (my phone). I guess the issue is only on the tablet rendering. Anyone have ideas on this?